# Using interval in AJAX callback, variable not updating

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am able to successfully retrieve data using the `get_data()` function inside a `setInterval`. However, when the AJAX function finds a new price, calling the `get_data()` function does not return the new price, but continues to return the price given on its first iteration (explained by the two console log lines)

How can I have the price updated properly when calling `get_data()` inside an interval?

```
// Collect price data into array
var interval = 1000;
var arr = [];

function price() {
    setInterval(function() {
        get_data(function(result) {
            arr.push(result);
            console.log('updated price: ' + arr[0]); // not updated correctly
        });
    }, 1000);

    function get_data(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://' + domain + '/site-options/',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: fase,
            success: function(data) {
                var price = data['gbp_price'];
                var abs_change = data['gbp_abs_change'];
                var p_change = data['gbp_change'];
                var market_cap = data['gbp_market_cap'];
                var today_max = data['gbp_today_max'];
                var today_min = data['gbp_today_min'];

                var obj = {
                    'price'      : price,
                    'abs_change' : abs_change,
                    'p_change'   : p_change,
                    'market_cap' : market_cap,
                    'max'        : today_max,
                    'min'        : today_min
                };

                console.log('price: ' + price); // updated correctly

                if (callback) 
                    callback(obj);
            }
        });
    }
}
price();
```

Comment: Set `cache: false` in the AJAX request. Also note that AJAX polling is a very bad pattern to use. You are effectively DDOS-ing your own server. Look in to websockets instead if you want to keep data in sync with a low interval.

Comment: Thanks guys, cache: false doesn't do the trick sadly. @RoryMcCrossan I wish I knew what that was. I'm going to run a test on whether the data has changed before doing anything if that helps.

Comment: Um, do you know what `arr.push(result);` does? It adds the item to the end of the array. And you are reading the first index with `arr[0]`. Of course the first index does not update since you just added the new item to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When pushing data into an array stack it will at it to the end. You are then logging the first value each time so you can either avoid .push()-ing and just run:

```
console.log( result.price );
```

or:

```
console.log('updated price: ' + ( arr.length - 1 ) );
```